# SWIFT - MPMediaPickerController -init error

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I have two view controllers, one with mediapicker and one with the actual player.
so i done this code:

first view

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class WelcomeView: UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController = MPMediaPickerController.self(mediaTypes:MPMediaType.Music)
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
mediapicker1 = mediaPicker
mediaPicker.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

var mediapicker1 = MPMediaPickerController()

@IBAction func selectsong(sender: AnyObject) {
self.presentViewController(mediapicker1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("you picked: \(mediaItemCollection)")
    selectedelement = mediaItemCollection

    let vc = MainView(nibName: "MainView", bundle: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) 
}

var selectedelement = MPMediaItemCollection()
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestView: MainView = segue.destinationViewController as MainView
    DestView.selectedsong = selectedelement
 }}
```

and the player view

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class MainView: UIViewController {

var play = MPMusicPlayerController()
var selectedsong = MPMediaItemCollection()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    func prepareToPlay() -> Bool{
    let myplayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
    myplayer.setQueueWithItemCollection(selectedsong)
    play = myplayer
    myplayer.play()
    return true
    }}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}}
```

but when i tap start the xcode gives me this error:
"MPMediaItemCollectionInitException', reason: '-init is not supported, use -initWithItems:"

I searched on google about this, and found something like "I not actually running the query in the background"

so i dont realy understand what to do))

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're initializing your variables instead of just declaring them and your choice of initializer is not valid.

```
var selectedsong = MPMediaItemCollection()
//       missing "items:" in constructor ^
```

Since you're setting `selectedsong` in your `prepareForSegue` anyways, you should simply declare it and not try to initialize a value:

```
var selectedsong : MPMediaItemCollection
```

---

Side note: the same is true of `play`. You are resetting its value in `prepareToPlay` before you use it for the first time, so this initial value is thrown away every time anyway.

```
var play : MPMusicPlayerController
```